Is it possible to have access to update app even if we are targeting old android version?
I wanted access to update my app, but the problem is I am facing system issues while generating aab file of Android 11, 12, 13 and 14. But in case of Android 10 it is being generated. That is what I need to clarify that if it is possible that I want access to update app as well as I am targeting android 10 (old version).
Currently, My app is available for all versions of Android above 7.0
